# dual boot: Windows 7 and OSX - which to install first?

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation, mac-osx

The goal is to install Windows (7 in this case) and OSX on a netbook in a dual-boot configuration. The details of the netbook isn't important in this case, I don't think, as the compatibility details have been worked out OK. (it's a Lenovo s10e).

I have purchased Mac OSX separately for this installation to ensure continued good karma.

The question is around which to install first - Windows or Mac OSX? Does one not know how to recognize the other, thereby necessitating which needs to go first?

Additionally, are there any bootloaders which will help with a non-text based user interface; [hopefully something prettier than this](http://windows7forums.com/attachments/windows-7-discussion/130d1232724107-dual-boot-two-hard-drives-dual-boot-screen_png.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using GRUB on my laptop as the primary bootloader to triple-boot between Windows, OS X and Linux (final goal is having KX Light as the fourth OS basically booting right into an Amiga emulator ;)

To get OS X86 (patched version of OS X mind you) GRUB just chain-calls the OS X Darwin bootloader copied over to the Linux grub configuration folder - works just fine after some tweaking (removing ugly delays, pointing to the right partition and stuff).

Order of install was Windows Vista (or 7 in your case), OS X86 and finally Ubuntu and GRUB.

And no, it's just text... but it's just a boot selector screen, it's not like I mind that anyway ^^

Here's [some guide](http://atechkid.blogspot.com/2008/10/dual-boot-vista-and-osx86-easy-way.html) to doing it in a more easy way I think. There're lots of dual-booting guides for Windows and OS X86 - easy to find.